# segmentation of texture with k means

Tags: matlab

I have a texture pic and want to segment it using K-mean algorithm.
I wrote:

```
clc;clear;
I=imread('jyFMW.jpg');
[r c]=size(I)
%figure
%imshow(I)
%imhist(I)
R=double(I(:));
k=5;
[IDX,C]=kmeans(R,k);
B=zeros(size(C));
B(find( C == 1 )) = 0;
B(find( C == 2 )) = 50; 
B(find( C == 3)) = 100; 
B(find( C == 4 )) = 150; 
B(find( C == 5 )) = 200; 
S=reshape(B,r,c);
figure
imshow(S)
```

but im not sure about this,Would you please help me? i need have a result like:
http://upload7.ir/images/91105509914760477547.jpg

For this input image:
http://upload7.ir/images/20702551133388585947.jpg

Comment: the main pic is that http://upload7.ir/viewer.php?file=20702551133388585947.jpg

Comment: what your input image lookes like? Is it color image or gray-scale? Do you understand the meaning of applying k-means directly to the gray levels of the image, discaring any spatial information?

Comment: and why do you think k-means is going to help you here?

Comment: thanks for your attention.my input image is a gray-scale texture image.I should test some image segmentation methods on these pic.